# std::pair of std::string and custom class fails to copy on std::map::insert(std::make_pair(string, class))

Tags: c++, insert, std-pair

This error:

```
error C2678: binary '=' : no operator found which takes a left-hand operand of type 'const std::string' (or there is no acceptable conversion)  c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio 10.0\vc\include\utility  216
```

occurs on this function's only line:

```
void Animation::AddAnimation(std::string name, AnimationFrameSet& animation) {
    _animations.insert(std::make_pair(name, animation));
}
```

`_animations` is a `std::map<std::string, AnimationFrameSet>`

AnimationFrameSet declares an operator=(...) and a copy constructor, but weirdly enough, the compiler says it fails on the attempted copying of `const std::string`...even though the string isn't even being passed in as a `const`.

I can't for the life of me figure out (or even remember! :P) why this is/should throwing/throw an error.

Thanks.

**EDIT**

The reason I'm a little confused why this is not working is that a different class uses a very similar implementation and it does not throw an error:

```
BITMAP* BitmapCache::GetBitmap(std::string filename) {
    //Return NULL if a bad filename was passed.
    if(filename.empty()) return NULL;
    if(exists(filename.c_str()) == false) return NULL;

    //Reduce incorrect results by forcing slash equality.
    filename = fix_filename_slashes(&filename[0]);

    //Clean the cache if it's dirty.
    CleanCache();

    //Search for requested BITMAP.
    MapStrBmpIter _iter = _cache.find(filename);

    //If found, return it.
    if(_iter != _cache.end()) return _iter->second;

    //Otherwise, create it, store it, then return it.
    BITMAP* result = load_bmp(filename.c_str(), NULL);
    if(result == NULL) return NULL;
    /*Similar insert line, a non-const std::string that was passed in is passed to a std::make_pair(...) function*/
    _cache.insert(std::make_pair(filename, result));
    return result;
}
```

typedefs:

```
typedef std::map<std::string, BITMAP*> MapStrBmp;
typedef MapStrBmp::iterator MapStrBmpIter;
```

Comment: Can you show us the `operator=`? What happens if you specify the type arguments to `make_pair` explicitly?

Comment: Have you included "#include <string>" ?

Comment: also try to provided a minimum code which gives the same problem

Comment: Based on the header path, I'm pretty sure visual studio 2010 prints out more than just that line. You might want to include that in your question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason why this is failing is because the std::map container you are using expects a const value as key value.

Check the documentation of std::map [here](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/stl/map/).

Example:

```
class TestClass
{
};

std::map< const std::string, TestClass > myMap;
std::pair< const std::string, TestClass > firstElement = std::make_pair("test", TestClass() );
myMap.insert( firstElement );
```

Answer (score 0):

Since `_animations` is a `std::map`, try using another method of inserting, such as:

```
_animations[name] = animation;
```

But the more important thing to check would be if the AnimationFrameSet class does have a valid copy constructor and assignment operator. If it doesn't you may want to use a smart pointer class such as:

```
typedef std::shared_ptr<AnimationFrameSet> AnimationFrameSetPtr;
```

Then the map would be:

```
std::map<std::string, AnimationFrameSetPtr>
```